# FastAPI - Unable to get auth token from middleware's Request object

Tags: python, api, rest, authentication, fastapi

Following [Starlette documentation](https://www.starlette.io/requests/) (FastAPI uses Starlette for middlewares), `response.headers["Authorization"]` should allow me to get the bearer token, but I get a `KeyError` saying no such attribute exists.

When I print `response.headers`, I get `MutableHeaders({'content-length': '14', 'content-type': 'application/json'})`.

Why is the authorization attribute not in the header despite of making a request with an `auth` header?

```py
@app.middleware("http")
async def validate_access_token(request: Request, call_next):
    response = await call_next(request)
    access_token = response.headers["Authorization"].split()
    is_valid_signature = jwt.decode(access_token[1], key=SECRET, algorithms=CRYPT_ALGO)
    
    if is_valid_signature:
        return response
    else:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, 
            detail='Invalid access token'
        )
```

Comment: And where did you expect the header to come from? Did you set it yourself hardcoded in your request? Or did you expect expect it to come back from your endpoint?

Comment: Yes I hardcoded it in. I added a token to the "Authorization" header on Postman

Comment: But does your code explicitly take it from the request and adds it to the response? That doesn’t happen automatically, as it would make no sense to return the bearer token to the end user?

Comment: Yeah when the user logs in, I return a JWT and the client-side app will then use it as the auth token. Is this not a good approach?

Comment: Oh I see, that was a silly mistake lol. Thank you for the suggestion regarding the Dependencies as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to retrieve the `Authorization` header from the `Respone` instead of the `Request` object (as you mentioned in the title of your question). Hence, you should instead use:

```py
access_token = request.headers['Authorization']
               ^^^^^^^
```

**or**

```py
access_token = request.headers.get('Authorization')
```

Additionally, instead of a middleware, it might be better to use [Dependencies](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/), along with [FastAPI's `OAuth2PasswordBearer`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/first-steps/#fastapis-oauth2passwordbearer) (you can find the implementation [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/efc12c5cdbede6922a033a5234c70cb22c4d204a/fastapi/security/oauth2.py#L140)), similar to [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73662576/17865804) (which demonstrates how to achieve authentication using the third-party package [FastAPI_Login](https://github.com/MushroomMaula/fastapi_login) - have a look at the relevant implementation [here](https://github.com/MushroomMaula/fastapi_login/blob/d84338c1957d3eba90bd46375ec1b6e708f2fba1/fastapi_login/fastapi_login.py#L20)).