# How to redirect an API request from a mobile front-end react app user according to their app url (origin)?

Tags: javascript, redirect, httprequest, fastapi, ionic-react

I am using FastAPI to redirect the user from the external payment page to the success page after their payment is succeeded.
The user will be paid in another payment gateway and then redirected back to the app URL as a response after payment is successful.

However, users may use different ports to open the apps (it is an Ionic React App).
For example, some users may open it in localhost:8000 or some users may open it in localhost:3000...
which cannot be hard-coded in the redirection link(e.g. localhost:8000/success-page/)

While I am hesitant to detect the origin/user IP address in the apps for redirection,
what will be the better practice for redirection given that the app user may use the app in different ports?

Thanks a lot!

I am currently hard-coded the FastAPI redirection URL and the mobile web app is opened in a fixed port localhost:8000 so that the redirection link will only be(localhost:8000/success-page/).
However, practically I think that I cannot control which port the user used to open the apps as the user may use different ports to open many apps.

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70689393/17865804) on how to obtain the origin URL.