# How to get user's IP address using Amazon API Gateway and FastAPI?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, fastapi, aws-api-gateway, x-forwarded-for

I am using Amazon API Gateway that forwards requests to a FastAPI server (I am not using nginx). I am trying to get the user's IP address in a FastAPI endpoint, but it does not seem to be working (`x_forwarded_for` is empty).

Here is a snippet of my FastAPI backend:

```
@app.post("/upload")
async def runUpload(file: UploadFile,request: Request, x_forwarded_for: str = Header(None)):
   userIp = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0].strip() if x_forwarded_for else request.client.host
```

This is how I start my server:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app,port=PORT,host='0.0.0.0',proxy_headers=True,forwarded_allow_ips="*")
```

when i print the request.headers i see (of course with correct numbers), so the data is here...

```
'forwarded': 'by=1.2.3.4;for=5.6.7.8;host=555.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com;proto=https'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FastAPI (starlette) get client real IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60098005/fastapi-starlette-get-client-real-ip)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70689393/17865804) might also prove helpful.

Comment: Nope those answers do not work..

Comment: I am not using another proxy. I am using Amazon Api Gateway. AFAIK, it should set it

Comment: yes it is. No example online has shown to take it from there... weird